# Dedicated server: network port going off

Tags: linux, ssh, port

I have recently bought a dedicated server on online.net website (dedibox, basic service), and I'm constantly encountering problems, making my server unavailable.

Randomly my server goes off (like every ~= 5 hours), stays off: on the console, "Server power" is declared as "off", and there is an error message "Your server's network port is off. Our network equipment may be on protective mode due to non-authorized network traffic.". I have to reboot the server (already did it ~= 10 times).

I tried to install again the os, and even different os, thinking maybe the one I was using was badly configured or instable, but nothing changes, even if the os is installed and not a single program is installed by me.

I contacted support, they told me the problem was on my side, I should check the logs, "If your server make down the switch it's because your network make an DHCP storm, or an flood.", but I found nothing special in it (well, some logs were displaying ssh bruteforce attacks, but not everytime the server locked the network). I have denyhosts blocking ssh attacks, denied direct root connection.

Has somebody an idea? Has somebody encountered similar problems?

Thanks in advance

Ps: will edit my post with some links to logs/stats if necesary, I don't have access right now to my server.

Comment: Please add a `dmesg` output after the server goes off (if you don't have KVM access and wonder how to do that without server access - adding something like `date && dmesg >> /var/log/dmesg.log` to cron should help) to determine if that's a hardware issue...

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting company is denying its problems:

> even if the os is installed and not a single program is installed by me.

you should change it, since if they cannot get their own template OS running, they probably wouldn't be able to provide reliable service.

If you are determined to stay with them, try registering a new account/requesting a new server [in another datacenter](http://www.iliad-datacenter.fr/datacenters). But I won't recommend it - not being able to run a template OS without problems and denying it shouldn't be tolerated...

Comment: Sad thing is that I bought a server for a year ^^"
Not that expensive, but still frustrating, and I'm kinda discouraged about taking new risks with my money.